# Solving an equation with a constraint involving not-equal

Tags: equation-solving, constraint

I am trying to solve an equation with a constraint involving not-equal.

For example:

$2 x + 3 y = 5$ with the constraint $2 x + 4 ≠ 2$.

How should I approach this?

#### Edit 1

I tried the suggestions in the comments. I am actually trying to get Mathematica to return a numerical set of values for each variable (which doesnt seem to work via the suggested methods). Any suggestions on this?

#### Edit 2:

I should have clarified. What I would like Mathematica to do is to give a range of values for both variables $x$ and $y$.

---

```
Reduce[{2 x + 3 y == 5, 2 x + 4 != 2}, {y}, Reals]
```

gives

> (x < -1 || x > -1) && y == 1/3 (5 - 2 x)

So there is x-range, but how to get y-range?

Comment: `!=` means not equal.

Comment: You would write: Solve[{2 x + 3 y == 5, 2 x + 4 != 2}, x]

Comment: `Reduce[{2 x + 3 y == 5, 2 x + 4 != 2}, x]` would be better.

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't give a fully simplified numerical expression. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What numerical expression would you find acceptable?

Comment: I was wondering if Mathematica could give something like x =/= -1 and y =/= 7/3 or something along the lines of that.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `FindInstance`? -- Oh, maybe not....

Comment: Try `FunctionRange[{1/3 (5 - 2 x), (x < -1 || x > -1)}, x, y]` ?

Comment: `Reduce[{2 x + 3 y == 5, 2 x + 4 != 2}, #, Reals] & /@ {x, y} ` yields `{(y < 7/3 || y > 7/3) && x == 1/2 (5 - 3 y), (x < -1 || x > -1) && 
  y == 1/3 (5 - 2 x)} `

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Reduce[{2 x + 3 y == 5, 2 x + 4 != 2}, {x, y}, Reals]
(*(x < -1 || x > -1) && y == 1/3 (5 - 2 x)*)
```

?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. It looks good - do you think Mathematica could give an explicit set of values that y can take? Or can it only find y in terms of x? Thanks!